# How to prevent direct access of script

Tags: php, javascript

I have a php script called from html  tag, as

```
<script src="js/myscript.php"> </script>
```

Please help me finding a php function to detect if this script is called directly or from script tag of my website.

I wish to prevent someone pasting link to address bar and getting content of myscript.php, as

```
http://www.mysite.com/js/myscript.php
```

Comment: This is not possible reliably.

Comment: You don't. If your site has any JavaScript code, then it can be viewed by any user of your site. Period.

Answer (score 1):

Not much you can do here other then check the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], which by no means is a secure way of doing this. Its pretty much impossible to do what your asking as there are simple ways around this.

Your best bet would be to obfuscate the code which would make it harder to read should they load the URL, but again, there are ways around this also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript, you CANNOT prevent everyone being able to see it. You can't expect a browser to be able to do what the script tells it to do without telling it what to do :)

Your file ext is a PHP, but it is in a js folder. If the output is only JS, you can't stop people being able to view it in any real reliable manner.